# Пропадает звук через несколько часов

Tags: ubuntu, аудио, alsa

Спустя некоторое время (несколько часов), пропадает звук в приложении (игра). После рестарта приложения звук воспроизводится нормально.

Для теста было написано простое приложение на [SDL2](https://www.libsdl.org/), которое воспроизводит синус. Проблема повторилась. Также было написано другое приложение на [libportaudio](http://www.portaudio.com/), был взят готовый [исходник](http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/paex__saw_8c_source.html) из примеров, проблема повторилась.

Чтобы избежать лишние прослойки, в итоге было написано простое тестовое приложение с использованием `libasound`, где также повторилась проблема и было обнаружено, что вызов функции `snd_pcm_writei` в случае пропадания звука не возвращает управление.

Пробовал Ubuntu 12.04 x32 (liveUSB), и Ubuntu 14.04 x32 (liveUSB). Также пробовал на трех различных материнских платах. В `virtual box` проблема не воспроизводится.

Подскажите, в какую сторону копать.

---

**UPDATE**

Проблема воспроизводится только при работе с LiveUSB. Если установить Ubuntu на жесткий диск, работает как положено.

Comment: alsa? а какже pulseaudio?

Comment: @ДенисКотляров вроде pulseaudio поверх alsa работает, или нет? (к тому, что если в alsa проблема, то тоже будет и в pulseaudio)

Comment: если работает pulseaudio то alsa идет как интерфейс и перенаправляет все через pulseaudio.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian так pulseaudio у вас есть или только alsa? Если есть - пробовали делать перезапуск не приложения, а PA? В dmesg (или куда у вас сообщения от PA сыпятся) есть какие-то записи в этот момент? Может быть срабатывает электросбережение и устройство отключается, а потом не включается корректно?

Comment: @МАН69К пробовал и с pulseaudio и без, примерно одинаково, разве что с pulseaudio дольше вроде работало (либо это была случайность). PA не пробовал перезапускать, сейчас стоит с сохранением логов, жду пока звук пропадет, чтобы посмотреть логи.

Comment: Каким способом записывали LiveUSB?

Comment: @NewDevelop с помощью [rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/)

Comment: А чо будет при cat /dev/urandom | aplay -fcd

Comment: полагаю, что дело в дровах. Возможно, у вас вообще ноут, а к ним Ubuntu наплевательски относитеться. У меня например, отключается Wi-fi  в течении 20 минут. Поищите обновление дров

Comment: Все равно несколько часов никто не продержится играть :)

Comment: Скорее всего это баг каких-то устаревших компонентов. Поставьте последнюю lts-версию убунты (18.04), сделайте ей `apt update` и `apt upgrade`, и затем уже проверяйте.

Answer (score 1):

Так как ubuntu в лайве не имеет установленных драйверов проблема заключается в отсутствие драйверов.

Answer (score 0):

Давайте рассуждать. Если на LiveUSB есть проблемы, а на основной тачке нет, то, возможно, проблема состоит в отсутствии драйверов на звук? (Как вариант)